# ListView backgroung color for each row android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, background-color

Im changing the background color of each row overriding onListItemClick with this piece of code

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// First time touching the item
if(mLastPosition==-1) {
    mLastPosition = position;
} else {
    mLocalBG.remove(String.valueOf(mLastId));
    v = l.getChildAt(mLastPosition);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mLastPosition = position;
}
mLocalBG.add(String.valueOf(id));
/* The issue: v is returning null right here, but only when touch a row that was below the first ones displayed, rows that needed to be scrolled down */
v = l.getChildAt(position);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}
```

As noted, it works perfectly till i scroll down to the next rows, after that  `View v` returns null everytime. Why is that happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding more info:

IMHO, it's probably happening in the rows that `newView` wasn't called. :/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is years old, but this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
v = l.getChildAt(position);
```

See [ViewGroup#getChildAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%)(). This method isn't overridden for ListView (though perhaps it should be) and only gives you visible views. Why? Off-scroll views don't exist! Remember, the same handful of views are recycled to save memory at the expense of weirdness like this.

Try this:

```
v = l.getChildAt(position - l.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

You'll also want to set the correct background in your adapter's `getView()`.